# Assigning values to array elements based on a lookup table

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a C# program wherein I need to populate an array based on a lookup table and set of string arrays with metadata. My lookup table looks like this (Table with key: transmitter, value: Array of receiver):

```
{
    LED1: ["px1","px2","px3"],
    LED2: ["px4","px5","px6"]
}
```

and my meta arrays looks like this (it is dynamic (just an example) and comes as a response from a DB query):

```
var transmitters = new string[] { "LED1", "LED2" };
var receivers = new string[] { "px1", "px2", "px3", "px4", "px5", "px6" };
```

My requirement is:

- If the transmitter LED1 or LED2 (or any other transmitter) is present in the lookup table, the value of the transmitter (i.e. ["px1","px2","px3"]) has to be compared with the receiver which are present in the lookup and led has to be marked yellow.
- Orphan transmitter or/ receiver has to be marked red.

**Example**

**Lookup**

```
{
        LED1: ["px1", "px2", "px3"],
        LED2: ["px5", "px8"]
}
```

Transmitters and receivers

```
var transmitters = new string[] { "led1", "led2" };
var receivers = new string[] { "px1", "px2", "px3", "px4", "px5", "px6" };
```

The result should be a list as:

```
led1-yellow
px1-yellow
px2-yellow
px3-yellow
led2-yellow
px5-yellow
px4-red
px6-red.
```

I have written code that works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      var transmitters = new string[] { "led1", "led2", "led3" };
      var receivers = new string[] { "px1", "px2", "px3", "px4", "px5", "px6" };
      var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() {
          { "led1", new string[] { "px1", "px2", "px3" } },
          { "led2", new string[] { "px5", "px8"} }
      };

      var blocks = new List<Block>();
      var blocksTracker = new List<string>();

      foreach (var transmitter in transmitters)
      {
        if (lookup.ContainsKey(transmitter))
        {
          var receiverLookup = lookup[transmitter];
          var intersection = receivers.Intersect(receiverLookup).ToArray();
          if (intersection.Length > 0)
          {
             blocks.Add(new Block() { Id = transmitter, status = "yellow"});
             blocksTracker.Add(transmitter);
            foreach (var receiver in intersection)
            {
              blocks.Add(new Block(){Id = receiver, status = "yellow"});
              blocksTracker.Add(receiver);
            }
          } else  
          {
            blocks.Add(new Block(){Id = transmitter, status = "red"});
            blocksTracker.Add(transmitter);   
          }
        }
      }

      var ungrouped = receivers.Except(blocksTracker).ToArray();

      foreach (var receiver in ungrouped)
      {
        blocks.Add(new Block(){Id = receiver, status = "red"});
        blocksTracker.Add(receiver);
      }

      foreach (var i in blocks)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(i.Id + "-"+i.status);
      }
    }

    public class Block
    {
      public string Id { get; set; }

      public string status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am new to C# and I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this. You can see the working Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d3E7n0).

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look. Also you can see it working https://dotnetfiddle.net/d3E7n0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
>         if (lookup.ContainsKey(transmitter))
>         {
>           var receiverLookup = lookup[transmitter];
> ```

This searches for the `KeyValuePair` twice. There's a more efficient approach:

```
        if (lookup.TryGetValue(transmitter, out var receiverLookup))
```

---

> ```
>       var ungrouped = receivers.Except(blocksTracker).ToArray();
>
>       foreach (var receiver in ungrouped)
>       {
>         blocks.Add(new Block(){Id = receiver, status = "red"});
>         blocksTracker.Add(receiver);
>       }
> ```

The `ToArray()` there is unnecessary: the enumerable can be left as a lazy enumerable because the only use is to iterate over it once.

---

> ```
>           var intersection = receivers.Intersect(receiverLookup).ToArray();
>           if (intersection.Length > 0)
>           {
>              blocks.Add(new Block() { Id = transmitter, status = "yellow"});
>              blocksTracker.Add(transmitter);
>             foreach (var receiver in intersection)
>             {
>               blocks.Add(new Block(){Id = receiver, status = "yellow"});
>               blocksTracker.Add(receiver);
>             }
>           } else  
>           {
>             blocks.Add(new Block(){Id = transmitter, status = "red"});
>             blocksTracker.Add(transmitter);   
>           }
> ```

This seems rather complicated. I think the whole thing could be simplified:

```
var transmittersPaired = new HashSet<string>();
var receiversPaired = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var transmitter in transmitters)
{
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(transmitter, out var receiverLookup) && receiverLookup.Any())
    {
        transmittersPaired.Add(transmitter);
        foreach (var receiver in receiverLookup)
        {
            receiversSeen.Add(receiver);
        }
    }
}

var blocks = new List<Block>();
foreach (var transmitter in transmitters)
{
    blocks.Add(new Block { Id = transmitter, status = transmittersPaired.Contains(transmitter) ? "yellow" : "red" });
}
foreach (var receiver in receivers)
{
    blocks.Add(new Block { Id = receiver, status = receiversPaired.Contains(receiver) ? "yellow" : "red" });
}
```

There's still some repeated code, which might be simplified in one of two ways. If there's a guarantee that the transmitters and receivers will never share IDs then `transmittersPaired` and `receiversPaired` could be merged into one set, and the `foreach` loops at the end could be merged into one loop over `transmitters.Concat(receivers)`. Alternatively, a method could be factored out.